# put xslt result in CDATA section with QXmlQuery from Module QtXmlPatterns

Tags: qt, xslt

I try to transform an xml by a xslt file. The output should contain a CDATA section. To do that i use the QXMLQuery object from qt 4.8.3.

I try something like this:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b>
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</a>
  <a>4</a>
</b>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <x>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./b/a"/>
    </x>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="b/a">
    <aa>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
      <xsl:element name="img"/>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </aa>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with other xslt editor this results in :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x>
  <aa><![CDATA[1<img/>]]></aa>
  <aa><![CDATA[2<img/>]]></aa>
  <aa><![CDATA[3<img/>]]></aa>
  <aa><![CDATA[4<img/>]]></aa>
</x>
```

using QXMLQuery results in:

```
Fehler XTSE0090 in file:///C:/work/2.xsl, bei Zeile 11, Spalte 46: Attribute disable-output-escaping cannot appear on the element text. Only the standard attributes can appear.
```

Is there an other way to do this?
Or if there is no way: Is there another free or open-source xslt parser for C++?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your XSLT processor doesn't support that attribute.  You could try using it on an `xsl:value-of` instead:

```
  <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;![CDATA['" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
  <xsl:element name="img"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="']]&gt;'" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

That's my best guess.